# MySQL left join performance issues

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have been having issues with MySQL (version 5.5) left join performance on a number of queries.  In all cases I have been able to work around the issue by restructuring the queries with unions and subselects (I saw some examples of this in the book *High Performance MySQL*).  The problem is this this leads to very messy queries.

Below is an example of two queries that produce the exact same results.  The first query is roughly two orders of magnitude slower than the second.  The second query is much less readable than the first.

As far as I can tell these sorts of queries are not performing poorly because of bad indexing.  In all cases when I restructure the query it runs just fine.  I have also tried carefully looking at the indexes and using hints to no avail.

Has anyone else run into similar issues with MySQL?  Are there any server parameters I should try tweaking?  Has anyone found a cleaner way to work around this sort of issue?

### Query 1

```
select
  i.id,
  sum(vp.measurement * pol.quantity_ordered) measurement_on_order
from items i
left join (vendor_products vp, purchase_order_lines pol, purchase_orders po) on
  vp.item_id = i.id and
  pol.vendor_product_id = vp.id and
  pol.purchase_order_id = po.id and
  po.received_at is null and
  po.closed_at is null
group by i.id

explain:
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                 | key               | key_len | ref                                 | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | index  | NULL                          | PRIMARY           | 4       | NULL                                |  241 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | po    | ref    | PRIMARY,received_at,closed_at | received_at       | 9       | const                               |    2 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pol   | ref    | purchase_order_id             | purchase_order_id | 4       | nutkernel_dev.po.id                 |    7 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vp    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,item_id               | PRIMARY           | 4       | nutkernel_dev.pol.vendor_product_id |    1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------+-------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

### Query 2

```
select
  i.id,
  sum(on_order.measurement_on_order) measurement_on_order
from (
  (
    select
      i.id item_id,
      sum(vp.measurement * pol.quantity_ordered) measurement_on_order
    from purchase_orders po
    join purchase_order_lines pol on pol.purchase_order_id = po.id
    join vendor_products vp on pol.vendor_product_id = vp.id
    join items i on vp.item_id = i.id
    where
      po.received_at is null and po.closed_at is null
    group by i.id
  )
  union all
  (select id, 0 from items)
) on_order
join items i on on_order.item_id = i.id
group by i.id

explain:
+------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table      | type   | possible_keys                 | key                            | key_len | ref                                 | rows | Extra                                        |
+------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1   | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                          | NULL                           | NULL    | NULL                                | 3793 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  1   | PRIMARY      | i          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY                        | 4       | on_order.item_id                    |    1 | Using index                                  |
|  2   | DERIVED      | po         | ALL    | PRIMARY,received_at,closed_at | NULL                           | NULL    | NULL                                |   20 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2   | DERIVED      | pol        | ref    | purchase_order_id             | purchase_order_id              | 4       | nutkernel_dev.po.id                 |    7 |                                              |
|  2   | DERIVED      | vp         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,item_id               | PRIMARY                        | 4       | nutkernel_dev.pol.vendor_product_id |    1 |                                              |
|  2   | DERIVED      | i          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                       | PRIMARY                        | 4       | nutkernel_dev.vp.item_id            |    1 | Using index                                  |
|  3   | UNION        | items      | index  | NULL                          | index_new_items_on_external_id | 257     | NULL                                | 3380 | Using index                                  |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL    | NULL                          | NULL                           | NULL    | NULL                                | NULL |                                              |
+------+--------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have no idea why the second is faster, can you give us more details?

Comment: I guess I could provide some more details of the table structure, size, indexes, etc. of the tables involved in these queries. However, I'm afraid I might be wasting your time in time digging into the specifics this particular query.  I'm not terribly curious about this specific query as much as the pattern I used to work around it (unions + subselects replacing left joins), if anyone else has run into similar issues, and if there is a better workaround.  Still, if you think it pertinent, what other details would be most helpful?

Comment: Excuse the very late comment on this (question turned up while looking for something else), but in this situation isn't the 2nd mainly more efficient as it is doing INNER JOINs and so rejecting those without a matching vp or pol table record, while the first is including those without matching records but then having to deal with the resulting NULL records when doing the calculation for the SUM (and potentially having far more records when doing this aggregate function)